# Python - Is there a way to get (str, index) instead of (index, str) using enumerate?

Tags: python, enumerate

For example,

```
test = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
print ([(i, test) for i, test in enumerate(test)])
>> [(0, 'test1'), (1, 'test2'), (2, 'test3')]
```

Is there a way to instead get [('test', 0), ('test2', 1), ('test3', 2)]?

Comment: Switch`test` with `i`. `[(t, i) for i, t in enumerate(test)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from the obvious genexpr/listcomp wrapper:

```
# Lazy
((x, i) for i, x in enumerate(test))

# Eager
[(x, i) for i, x in enumerate(test)]
```

you could use `map` (`future_builtins.map` on Py2) and `operator.itemgetter` to do the reversal at the C layer for extra speed:

```
from future_builtins import map  # Only on Py2, to get Py3-like generator based map

from operator import itemgetter

# Lazy, wrap in list() if you actually need a list, not just iterating results
map(itemgetter(slice(None, None, -1)), enumerate(test))

# More succinct, equivalent in this case, but not general reversal
map(itemgetter(1, 0), enumerate(test))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
test = ["test", "test2", "test3"]
print ([(test1, i) for i, test1 in enumerate(test)])
```

I did fix a minor typo you had in your beginning code.  I changed `i, test` to `i, test1`.

And I switched `(i,test1)` to `(test1,i)`.

Comment: If you're unpacking and repacking anyway, just repack in reverse order and skip the slicing...

Comment: Oh yeah... that would make more sense.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply switch the variables in the list comprehension statement.

```
test = ["test", "test2", "test3"]
print ([(test,i) for (i,test) in enumerate(test)])
```

result:

```
[('test', 0), ('test2', 1), ('test3', 2)]
```